# Generating a python egg instead of a wheel

Tags: python, egg, python-wheel

I am sucessfully creating a python egg with this command:

python setup.py bdist -d C:\temp

I have configured setup.cfg, maniteft.in, description.rst and everything else.

When I run bdist command, I get a this:

[image]

However, I do not want to create a egg file... I want to create a *.whl file.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer!

The command is:

**python setup.py bdist_wheel -d C:\temp**